# Type script error reduce when loop on array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects like this

```
type AnyType = {
  name: 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
  isAny:boolean;
};

const myArray :AnyType[] =[
  {name:'A',isAny:true},
  {name:'B',isAny:false},
]
```

I want to run on `myArray` with `reduce` to get array for name only

```
const namesArray=myArray.reduce<AnyType['name'][]>((a,b)=>{
  return b.name;
},[])
```

but I get a typeScript error

```
(parameter) b: AnyType
BugFinder: No overload matches this call.BugFinder: 
  Overload 1 of 6, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: ("A" | "B" | "C")[], currentValue: AnyType, currentIndex: number, array: AnyType[]) => ("A" | "B" | "C")[], initialValue: ("A" | "B" | "C")[]): ("A" | ... 1 more ... | "C")[]', gave the following error.BugFinder: 
    Argument of type '(a: ("A" | "B" | "C")[], b: AnyType) => "A" | "B" | "C"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: ("A" | "B" | "C")[], currentValue: AnyType, currentIndex: number, array: AnyType[]) => ("A" | "B" | "C")[]'.BugFinder: 
      Type '"A" | "B" | "C"' is not assignable to type '("A" | "B" | "C")[]'.BugFinder: 
        Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '("A" | "B" | "C")[]'.BugFinder: 
  Overload 2 of 6, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: ("A" | "B" | "C")[], currentValue: AnyType, currentIndex: number, array: AnyType[]) => ("A" | "B" | "C")[], initialValue: ("A" | "B" | "C")[]): ("A" | ... 1 more ... | "C")[]', gave the following error.BugFinder: 
    Argument of type '(a: ("A" | "B" | "C")[], b: AnyType) => "A" | "B" | "C"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: ("A" | "B" | "C")[], currentValue: AnyType, currentIndex: number, array: AnyType[]) => ("A" | "B" | "C")[]'.BugFinder: 
      Type '"A" | "B" | "C"' is not assignable to type '("A" | "B" | "C")[]'.BugFinder: 
        Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '("A" | "B" | "C")[]'.
```

[playground](https://playcode.io/826017/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna 'map' the array to a different array, you should use the *myArray.map* method;
But if you want to specifically use reduce, let's say to also filter in the process, then the problem is with the reducer callback.
The reducer **should return the accumulator**, which in your case is an array of names;
This is the error TS is giving you, you're returning a name (of the current element) instead of an array of names.

This is an example of a reduce which maps and filters at the same time:

```
const namesArray = myArray.reduce<AnyType['name'][]>( ( accumulatorArr, currentValue ) => {
  if ( currentValue.isAny ) {
    accumulatorArr.push( currentValue.name );
  }
  return accumulatorArr;
}, [] );
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value is an array:

```
const NamesArray = myArray.reduce<AnyType["name"][]>(
  (a, { name }) => [...a, name],
  []
);
```

Another way using `Array#map`:

```
const NamesArray = myArray.map<AnyType["name"]>(({ name }) => name);
```

Comment: my question is about to reduce

Comment: answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Array.reduce(), then this will be useful. But as @majed Badawi mentioned, we can do it using Array.map() easily.

```js
interface AnyType {
  name: 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
  isAny: boolean;
}

const myArray: AnyType[] = [
  { name: 'A', isAny: true },
  { name: 'B', isAny: false },
];

const namesArray = myArray.reduce((a, b) => {
  a.push(b.name);
  return a;
}, [] as string[]);
```

NOTE: I did some changes to your type declaration as well. This is the way that I preferred to use it. Please change it to your form if you prefer that way!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const NamesArray=myArray.reduce<AnyType['name']|[]>((a:AnyType['name']|[],b:AnyType)=>{ 
  return b.name;
},[])
```